# why material UI components dose not work in app(page.js) in next.js ,like Grid

Tags: material-ui, next.js13

I installed next.js and also using material UI. From the material UI component I used Grid component in SSR page.js which is the home page. but when I try to see that in my browser, it shows this :

*Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Element type is invalid. Received a promise that resolves to: undefined. Lazy element type must resolve to a class or function.*

And when I remove the Grid component from page.js, the error message is gone, and the site appears well.
Here is the page code:

```
import LatestNews from '@/components/ui/LatestNews/LatestNews';
import { Grid } from '@mui/material';


const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <>

      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item="1" xs={8}>
          <LatestNews/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item="2" xs={4}>
          sideBar
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

I tried to make a newspaper webpage that has two column and has some news under it and I want to use Grid for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add use client to the top of whatever component is using mui components. Not sure why mui doesnt seem to support server sided components yet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).